# Can I remove the ctrl-z key binding in my shell?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, shell, gnu-screen

The background for this question: I currently have to do a lot of my work in terminal over ssh, and I use screen quite a bit. Because I found the ctrl-a key binding for screen commands so annoying since I'm accustomed to using ctrl-a to go to the beginning of a line, I changed it to ctrl-z. The only problem with this is that when I'm in Matlab, think I am in Screen but am not, pressing ctrl-z will instantly kill my Matlab session, because ctrl-z is the key binding for suspending processes in *nix.

So the question is: can I remove the key binding for ctrl-z in my shell so that it does no longer suspend a process?

My shell is terminal.app on OSX.

Comment: Does Ctrl-Z really *kill* Matlab? The way suspension works is that you get back your shell prompt (at least on the command line). If you're done suspending, you can continue the suspended program with `fg` (place it in the foreground again).

Comment: Thanks, Jens! You are absolutely right. I thought it was killed since I didn't see Matlab in top, but fg brings it back. That solves my problem :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The <kbd>^Z</kbd> binding is not configured in the shell, but in your *TTY*, the pseudo-device that lets you talk to the physical terminal or, as is typical nowadays, to a terminal emulator program. The TTY carries settings that tell the kernel how to react to keyboard input reported by the device or emulator.

Settings are changed using the `stty` command:

```
stty susp "^P"
```

`stty` accepts a setting name and its value; in this case the setting name is `susp` for key that suspends the process, and the value is a key combination, such as <kbd>^P</kbd>. Type `stty -a` or refer to [`man stty`](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stty.1.html) for a list of available settings.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your matlab in a script named `matlab.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap "" TSTP
/path/to/matlab-executable
```

That will ignore the TSTP signal usually sent by Ctrl-Z.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to choose a different escape character for screen.

I use the null character. I have the following in my `$HOME/.screenrc`:

```
escape ^@^@
```

The null character can (usually) be entered as <kbd>Ctrl-Space</kbd>, which is very easy to type. And of course if I need to send an actual null character to a program (for example, it's bound to `set-mark-command` in Emacs), I just type <kbd>Ctrl-Space</kbd> twice.

(This sometimes causes problems when I'm using a device or terminal emulator that can't send the null character, but that's rare.)

Another possibility is <kbd>Ctrl-]</kbd>:

```
escape ^]^]
```

which is also easy to type on a US keyboard. (I actually use that in a screen session that runs nested inside my primary screen session, but that's probably more than you want to know.) The only conflict I typically run into with that is that it's the default escape character for the `telnet` command.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use ctrl-space for something else, though, and ] is not so easily accessible on my Scandinavian keyboard.

Comment: For Emacs users, if you want to disable suspending when inside Emacs, this may be of help: `(define-key global-map (kbd "C-z") 'undo)` and `(define-key global-map (kbd "C-x C-z") 'undo)`.